# Emulate http_file but for a file from another repository

Tags: bazel

I'm including a repository that has an `extra_deps` rule of the form:

```
maybe(
    http_file,
    name = "external_dependency",
    downloaded_file_path = "foo.h",
    sha256 = "<some_sha>",
    urls = ["https://example.com/foo.h"],
)
```

If I have an existing repository, `foo_repo`, that provides `foo.h`, how can I substitute the target for it in place of `external_dependency`? `http_file` apparently provides `@external_dependency//file`, so I can't simply define an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl as a reference, you can define a custom repository rule that provides `@external_dependency//file`. For example:

```
def _repository_file(ctx):
    ctx.file("WORKSPACE", "workspace(name = \"{name}\")".format(name = ctx.name))
    ctx.file("file/BUILD.bazel", """
filegroup(
    name = "file",
    srcs = ["{}"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""".format(ctx.attr.source))

repository_file = repository_rule(
    attrs = {"source": attr.label(mandatory = True, allow_single_file = True)},
    implementation = _repository_file,
    doc = """Analogue of http_file, but for a file in another repository.

Usage:
repository_file(
    name = "special_file"
    source = "@other_repo//path/to:special_file.txt",
)
    """,
)
```

Now use:

```
repository_file(
    name = "external_dependency",
    source = "@foo_repo//path/to:foo.h",
)
```